# Collision check between objects in canvas always in the positive

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, collision-detection

Why is my collision detection between the Snake and the SnakeFood object not working?

This is my Snake constructor:

```
 class Snake {
   constructor() {
    this.x = 10;
    this.y = 10;
    this.xspeed = 1;
    this.yspeed = 0;
    this.scl = 20;
    this.height = this.scl;
    this.width = this.scl;
    //eatenfood technically is 1 for the snake head.
    this.size = 0;
    this.tail = [];
  }

  direction(x, y) {
    this.xspeed = x;
    this.yspeed = y;
  }

  update() {
    if (this.tail.length === this.size) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.tail.length - 1; i++) {
        this.tail[i] = this.tail[i + 1];
      }
    }
    this.tail[this.size -1] = { x: this.x, y: this.y };

    this.x = this.x + this.xspeed;
    this.y = this.y + this.yspeed;
  }

  show(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00b273';
    ctx.fillRect(this.x * this.scl, this.y * this.scl, this.scl, this.scl);
  }
}
```

This is my SnakeFood constructor:

```
class SnakeFood {
  constructor(width, height) {
    this.x = 15;
    this.y = 15;
    this.width = 20;
    this.height = 20;
    //type, color, size
  }

  show(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(this.x * 20, this.y * 20, this.width + 10, this.height + 10);
  }
}
```

This is how I am checking for collision in another file.:

```
function foodCollision() {
  let rect1 = snake;
  let rect2 = food;

  if ((rect1.x < (rect2.x + rect2.width)) &&
   ((rect1.x + rect1.width) > rect2.x) &&
   (rect1.y < (rect2.y + rect2.height)) &&
   ((rect1.y + rect1.height) > rect2.y)) {
    console.log('collision!');
  } else {
    console.log('no collision');
  } 
 }
```

Collision check always prints out 'Collision!' even when the snake is no where near the snakeFood object... I resorted to implementing MDN's Rectangle Collision Detection with no success.

This is how I draw my objects in the main file:

```
function draw() {
  //draw canvas
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  if (wallCollision(canvas.width, canvas.height)) {
    playing = !playing;
    console.log('collided with walls', snake.x, 'x', snake.y, 'y');
  }
  food.show(ctx);
  snake.show(ctx);
  snake.update();

  if (playing) {
    setTimeout(draw, 1000/10);
  }
}
```

My imports:

```
import Snake from './snake.js';
import SnakeFood from './snakeFood.js';

const canvas = document.getElementById('snake_canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;
const snake = new Snake();
const food = new SnakeFood(width, height);
let playing = true;
```

Comment: I manually added numbers for Snakes this.x and this.y to see why it was not working. Did the same for SnakeFood.

Comment: Hey there! Can you please include your code in your question directly? Links to screenshots are [generally discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Sorry ! I will edit this real quick.

Comment: Haven't looked at the rest of it, but `(rect1.y + (rect1.height > rect2.y)))` in your collision check has misplaced parentheses.

Comment: Oh wow, awkward. I fixed the parenthesis but my current issue still exists.